# Prove $\det(e^{tA})=e^{t\cdot{tr} (A)}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder the condition of A to make the following statement true: $\det(e^{tA})=e^{t\cdot{tr} (A)}$, where A is an $n\times n$ matrix. If A is diagonalizable, then the statement can be proved. So, will the statement holds for A which isn't diagonalizable? I have tried using the Jordan form, but it is too complicated to obtain the result. Thank you!

Comment: The matrix exponential of a Jordan block is upper triangular, and the diagonal entries are exactly what you'd expect. So you should be able to take the determinant, matrix exponential, and trace of a Jordan block.

Comment: Another common approach is to use limits: start by proving that the statement holds whenever $A$ is diagonalizable.  Then, use the fact that both functions are continuous and that for any $A$, there is a sequence $A_n \to A$ in which each $A_n$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Triangularize the matrix $A$.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the fact that exponential(J) is still upper triangular!